# Assigning memory variable to storage variable, what happens?

Tags: solidity, ether, storage, memory

I'm curious what happens if you try to do the next thing:

```
contract C {
    Struct S {
        uint a;
        uint b;
    }

    mapping(address => s) structs;

    function updateStructs(S sInstance) private {
        structs[msg.sender] = sInstance;
    }

    function addStruct (uint _a, uint _b) payable {
        S memory s = S({a: _a, b: _b});
        updateStructs(s);
    }
}
```

As I understood how variables work, the addStruct creates memory variable that has only function scope and will be deallocated once this transaction/message is processed. So what will remain in `structs[msg.sender]` after addStruct has been called? Will changing `updateStructs(S sInstance)` to `updateStructs(S storage sInstance)` change something?

Comment: `s` is not deallocated until `addStruct` returns. It might be helpful to understand stack frames, or activation records

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you store a memory variable into storage, then it will just copy the object into storage.

<s>Using the storage keyword in updateStructs actually won't do anything. Structs and arrays in functions are by default storage variables, so the memory object would actually be copied to storage right when you call updateStructs without the storage keyword.</s>

Edit: I stand corrected. @LibertyLocked is correct in their answer where they say you can't implicitly convert from memory to storage, so adding the storage keyword to the argument will make compilation fail.

Comment: Thanks for noticing, edited it. Sure about this, tried it? That is most obvious to me, but I wanted confirmation

Comment: My first part, yes. It'll copy the object in memory into storage. You can test this in Remix by adding a getStruct function that fetches the data of structs[msg.sender] from another transaction. If it wasn't copied to storage, then this data wouldn't exist. I was incorrect about my second part, as @LibertyLocked was correct in saying that there would be a compilation error. I updated my answer as well.

Answer (score 3):

In your example, if you'd change your code so that it looks like this

```
function updateStructs(S storage sInstance) private {
    structs[msg.sender] = sInstance;
}

function addStruct (uint _a, uint _b) payable {
    S memory s = S({a: _a, b: _b});
    updateStructs(s);
}
```

The code will not compile for the following reasons:

- `updateStructs` expects a struct instance from storage, but you are passing a struct instance in memory to it.
- There is no way for Solidity to figure out where to allocate and place the `s` in `addStruct` in storage.
- When you have `S memory sInstance` in your `updateStruct`, your `s` is **copied** into the stack frame of `updateStructs`. Also the `s` in `addStruct` is not deallocated until you return from `addStruct` (otherwise how would the function continue to run once it returns from `updateStruct`?).

To answer your question, in your example you must use `memory` instead of `storage`. In fact, it is implicitly `memory` in function arguments.

Comment: OK, to sum it up: at `S memory s = S({a: _a, b: _b});` the memory variable will be created in scope of `addStruct`, then, on `updateStructs(s);` the value of `s` is copied into the stack frame of `updateStructs` and then the `s` is copied from stack frame into the storage on `structs[msg.sender] = sInstance;`, right? My question was what will be at this location in storage.

Comment: There is only one storage location and that is `structs[msg.sender]`. It is only modified in `updateStructs`. `storage` keyword means a reference to storage location

Comment: So if you assign reference type variable that is in function stack to variable that is in storage, that variable is copied in storage?

Comment: The reference can get copied but the storage itself is never modified until you write to the reference

Comment: I think we find it hard to understand each other:)This is how I understand it: If you pass `s` to `updateStructs` it allocates bytes on stack and `s` keeps reference to those bytes. Once you do `structs[msg.sender] = sInstance` what happens? If the reference `s` is copied it does not make any sense since the stack allocated bytes are valid only in function scope and `structs[msg.sender]` will be pointing to randome bytes depending on the node it runs on. If the stack allocated bytes are copied to `structs[msg.sender]` it's fine but I still did not get confirmation on this from your answers.